# Change Div and Body Class on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [Backstretch plugin](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) to apply a stretched background image to my body element.

```
$("body.apples").backstretch("/apples.jpg");
$("body.oranges").backstretch("/oranges.jpg");
$("body.pears").backstretch("/pears.jpg");
```

I want my body class to change on refresh, so it shows the different background images on refresh. I'm also trying to work out how to only show the related `.wrapper` div below when the page is refreshed.

```
<body class="apples">
    <div class="wrapper apples">
        <h1>Something about Apples</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper oranges">
        <h1>Something about Oranges</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper pears">
        <h1>Something about Pears</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've managed to get the `.wrapper` div to change on refresh with this bit of JS:

```
function randomFromTo(from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }

    function RandomFruit() {
        var r = randomFromTo(1, $('.wrapper').length);
        $('.wrapper').hide().eq(r - 1).show();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        RandomFruit();
});
```

I've got a working demo here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/KCEtB

For some reason, I can't work out how to make the background and `.wrapper` div change.

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with an if else statement? And you would only need 1 wrapper

```
if ( $("body").hasClass("yourfruithere") ) {
$(".wrapper").html("<h1>Something about this fruit</h1><p>some content</p>");
```

Comment: I need a way to change the body class on refresh in addition to its related div.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the class of the body after the page loads, store that class as a variable, and show only the related content that also has that class:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t568m/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="oranges">
    <p class="oranges">Oranges</p>
    <p class="apples">Apples</p>
    <p class="pears">Pears</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var activeClass = $('div').attr('class');

    $('p').hide(),
    $('p.' + activeClass).show();
});
```

This function runs on document load just as a demo, but you would want to make sure you store the body's class as a variable *after* it loads on the page and is dynamically set by your other JS. Otherwise you may end up with a class of null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how comfortable you are working with objects in javascript, but here is one solution to your problem:

1. Create a Fruit object that contains the class name for the body, its own element, and its own image.  Each fruit object would have a Show() method that would change the class of the body element, the background image, and show itself.  It would also have a Hide() method for hiding itself.
2. Create an array of Fruit objects, and randomize an index.  Call Hide() on all of them, and then Show() on the chosen one.

Here is one implementation:

```
var run = function () {
    var apples = new Fruit(
        'apples',
        $('.apples'),
        'apple.jpg');
    var oranges = new Fruit(
        'oranges',
        $('.oranges'),
        'orange.jpg');
    var pears = new Fruit(
        'pears', 
        $('.pears'),
        'pear.jpg');

    var fruitBasket = new FruitBasket([apples, oranges, pears]);
    fruitBasket.displayRandomFruit();
}

var Fruit = function (className, element, image) {
    this.show = function () {
        $(element).show();
        $('body').backstretch(image);
        $('body').removeClass().addClass(className);
    }

    this.hide = function () {
        $(element).hide();
    }
}

var FruitBasket = function (fruitList) {
    this.displayRandomFruit = function () {
        var randomFruitIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitList.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {
            fruitList[i].hide();
        }
        fruitList[randomFruitIndex].show();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    run();
});
```

[Here it is on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NUQe9/5/)

Comment: That's great, but my problem with this answer is the two other elements are being hidden on the page. I'd like to remove them from the document completely if they're not being shown. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure.  jQuery's .html() function can be used to replace the contents of an element.  So, remove the Fruit.hide() method and all calls to it, and modify the Fruit.show() method to do something like $('body').html(element) instead of $('body').show();